# How to exit from recursive function call

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, search, review

Problem Statment: Find the missing number in the array
You are given an array of positive numbers from 1 to n, such that all numbers from 1 to n are present except one number x. You have to find x. The input array is not sorted. Look at the below array and give it a try before checking the solution.

3,7,1,2,8,4,5
n = 8
missing number = 6

My Solution I tried but no luck. Basically, I am not sure how to exit the recursive function call

````
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array={3,7,1,2,8,4,5};
        int i=1;
        int missingItem=array[0]+1;
        System.out.println(checkMissingItem(array,i,missingItem));
    }

    public static int checkMissingItem(int [] array,int j,int mitem)
    {
      //  System.out.println(array.length);
        for(int x=0;x< array.length;x++)
        {   if(mitem>array.length)
        {
            mitem=array[j]+1;
            j=j+1;
            checkMissingItem(array,j,mitem);
        }
            if(mitem==array[x])
            {
              mitem=array[j]+1;
              j=j+1;
                if(j==array.length)
                {
                    return mitem;
                }else
              checkMissingItem(array,j,mitem);
            }


        }
 return mitem;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Why you are not sorting?

Comment: Another approach: sum of first n natural numbers is `n*(n+1)/2`. You can deduct the actual sum from this expected sum and get the missing number.

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion to solve this problem? How do you expect it to help? In your own words, how is the code intended to work, step by step?

Answer (score 1):

#### Given:

---

- An array **A** of size ***n***.
- Array elements are a sequence from 1 to ***n*** , always starting from 1
- There is always only one missing number ***X***.

#### Then:

---

*expectedSum* = ***n*** * ( ***n*** + 1 ) / 2

*expectedSum* = sum(**A**) + ***X***

=>  ***X*** =  *expectedSum* - sum(**A**)

#### Example:

---

**A** = `[ 2 , 7 , 1 , 4 , 5 , 3 , 8 ]`

*expectedSum* = `8 * ( 8 + 1 ) / 2`

=> *expectedSum* =  `8 * 9 / 2`

=> *expectedSum* = `72 / 2`

=> *expectedSum* = **36**

***X*** = 36 - sum(**A**)

=> ***X*** = 36 - `( 2 + 7 + 1 + 4 + 5 + 3 + 8 )`

=> ***X*** = 36 - 30

=> ***X*** = 6